# Does Vorinclex help its controller or its owner?

Tags: magic-the-gathering, mtg-commander

I play a [Vorinclex, Voice of Hunger](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Vorinclex%2C%20Voice%20of%20Hunger) commander deck casually with friends. If one of my opponents plays [Mind Control](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Mind%20Control) (or something similar) and takes control of Vorinclex, do the triggered abilities now benefit my opponent and hurt me? That is, does it help its controller or the owner?

Also, since my opponent tapped lands to play Mind Control while Vorinclex was still mine, I think the lands he tapped to cast Mind Control stays tapped next turn. Is my thinking here correct?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ordeal of Heliod and changing creature control](http://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/13043/ordeal-of-heliod-and-changing-creature-control)

Answer (score 4):

All instances of the word *"you"* on an ability refer the controller of the source of that ability.

> **109.5.** The words “you” and “your” on an object refer to the object’s controller, its would-be controller (if a player is attempting to play, cast, or activate it), or its owner (if it has no controller). For a static ability, this is the current controller of the object it’s on. For an activated ability, this is the player who activated the ability. For a triggered ability, this is the controller of the object when the ability triggered, unless it’s a delayed triggered ability. To determine the controller of a delayed triggered ability, see rules 603.7d–f.

If an opponent gains control of Vorinclax, then that opponent gets extra mana from tapping lands, and yours do not untap during your untap step. In other words, Vorinclax controlled by an opponent hurts you and helps your opponent.

When your opponent taps lands to pay for Mind Control, you control Vorinclax. Those lands will not untap during your opponent's next untap step.

Comment: If you're still looking for the rule, it's 109.5.

Comment: @murgtroid Perfect! There are over 400 occurrences of the word in the document, and for some reason, searching for "you" in quotes returns zero results using Google Chrome's ctrl+f function. Thanks a bunch.

Comment: And for the second question, they tapped the lands to pay for Mind Control while you still controlled Vorinclex, so they indeed stay tapped, just as they also only produced one mana at the time.

Comment: @Rainbolt For reference, I found it by looking in the glossary, which actually has an entry for "You, Your." And, as an aside, Ctrl+F (at least in Chrome) searches literal strings, and doesn't parse stuff like quotation marks.

Comment: @Jefromi I totally missed the second question. Fixed.

Comment: I think the problem with quotation marks comes down to the fact that the comprehensive rules are (for no good reason I can comprehend) no longer available in text format, so the 'smart' quotes are embedded in the document itself.

Comment: The comprehensive rules are in fact available in [text format](http://media.wizards.com/2015/docs/MagicCompRules_20150123.txt). However, it looks like that document *also* has the smart quotes. And you are correct that that is the problem: a search for "you" using smart quotes copied from the document does correctly find rule 109.5.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki Wizards unfortunately has archived the old page: http://archive.wizards.com/Magic/tcg/article.aspx?x=magic/rules and it still ranks very well, but hasn't been updated. The new "rules and formats" page: http://magic.wizards.com/en/game-info/gameplay/rules-and-formats links to the current comprehensive rules: http://magic.wizards.com/en/gameinfo/gameplay/formats/comprehensiverules which still have three formats.

Answer (score -2):

As a rule of thumb - always assume controller unless the card says otherwise