# MTG Curse of misfortune

Tags: magic-the-gathering

Recently I made a deck to have fun with when I play with family/friends. So I played [Curse of Misfortunes](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bCurse%20of%20Misfortunes%5d) on target player, and he simply didn't understand the card, saying "Why did you cast this on me? when I don't have any curses in my deck? You're supposed to cast it on yourself so that you can use it." So I told him why would I want to curse myself? and add more curses to myself? So he then asks "I don't understand this card. Henceforth I won't be getting any curses from this card unless you can prove it" I tried to explain it by telling him that I get to pull curses from my deck and give it to him. And that there is a difference between this curse and other curses, because the other curses say Enchanted player gets this and that. While Curse of misfortune doesn't say any of that so it means that I get the ability of that card to place curses on him. So he simply said the same thing and didn't understand it. So I questioned myself too, therefore me asking this to you guys.

Another question, If I play curses on players, are those enchanted cards still considered mine? Ex. I play a curse on target players, and I have [Sphere of Safety](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bSphere%20of%20Safety%5d) out, and a player attacks me. Do they have to tap as many mana to as many curses I've given?

Comment: I don't think this question is a duplicate of the question Gendolkari mentioned. It is not obvious that the "You may search" ability printed on Curse of Misfortunes applies to the controller rather than the enchanted player. I do think this question is a duplicate of [Ordeal of Heliod and changing creature control](http://boardgames.stackexchange.com/q/13043/6692), which covers both who controls the enchantment and also who gets the effect of the enchantment.

Answer (score 4):

Any permanent(cards that stick around like creatures, enchantments, artifacts, lands) that you play are under your control unless it specifically says otherwise. You control the abilities of permanents that you control. Since you control Curse of Misfortunes, you control its ability, so when it says "you" or "your" on the card that refers to you since you are the controller of the card.

The card says enchant player which means as you are casting it, you choose a player as its target. When the enchantment resolves it enters the battlefield enchanting the player that had been targeted. That does not mean that player gains control of it just that it is in enchanting them.

Curse of Misfortunes works like you think it would. You curse your opponent with it, then you get to search out a curse at the beginning of your upkeep and attach it to that player.

You still control curses attached to your opponent so Sphere of Safety will count them towards the amount your opponent has to pay to attack you.

Answer (score 1):

Start with 109.5 from the [Comprehensive Rules](http://media.wizards.com/2017/downloads/MagicCompRules_20170119.txt):

> The words “you” and “your” on an object refer to the object’s controller, its would-be controller
>   
>   (if a player is attempting to play, cast, or activate it), or its owner (if it has no controller).
>   
>   For a static ability, this is the current controller of the object it’s on.
>   
>   For an activated ability, this is the player who activated the ability.
>   
>   For a triggered ability, this is the controller of the object when
>   
>   the ability triggered, unless it’s a delayed triggered ability.
>   
>   To determine the controller of a delayed triggered ability, see rules 603.7d–f.

To determine ​ "the controller of the object when the ability triggered" ,

go to 110.2 and 303.4e from those rules:

> A permanent’s owner is the same as the owner of the card that represents it
>   
>   (unless it’s a token; see rule 110.5a). A permanent’s controller is, by default,
>   
>   the player under whose control it entered the battlefield. Every permanent has a controller.
>
> An Aura’s controller is separate from the enchanted object’s controller or the enchanted player; the two need not be the same. If an Aura enchants an object, changing control of the object doesn’t change control of the Aura, and vice versa. Only the Aura’s controller can activate its abilities. However, if the Aura grants an ability to the enchanted object (with “gains” or “has”), the enchanted object’s controller is the only one who can activate that ability.

I can't find anything else that helps here.